# Change date to human time diff

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I am trying to change the date so it appears at 2 days ago, or 30 minutes ago.  I know I can use human time diff for this, but I don't know how to correctly add it to my site.  Every time I try to add it I get a syntax error.  I'm using the newspaper theme.  I found the code that gets the date in my theme files, does anyone know how I can change the code so human time diff is included?

*This question isn't about why I was getting a syntax error.  I know why, because I was adding in the code for human time diff wrong.  I'm not the best at coding, which is why I'm asking for help to add it correctly.

code from theme

```html
 function get_date($show_stars_on_review = true) {
        $visibility_class = '';
        if (td_util::get_option('tds_m_show_date') == 'hide') {
            $visibility_class = ' td-visibility-hidden';
        }

        $buffy = '';
        if ($this->is_review and $show_stars_on_review === true) {
            //if review show stars
            $buffy .= '<div class="entry-review-stars">';
            $buffy .=  td_review::render_stars($this->td_review);
            $buffy .= '</div>';

        } else {
            if (td_util::get_option('tds_m_show_date') != 'hide') {
                $td_article_date_unix = get_the_time('U', $this->post->ID);
                $buffy .= '<span class="td-post-date">';
                    $buffy .= '<time class="entry-date updated td-module-date' . $visibility_class . '" datetime="' . date(DATE_W3C, $td_article_date_unix) . '" >' . get_the_time(get_option('date_format'), $this->post->ID) . '</time>';
                $buffy .= '</span>';
            }
        }

        return $buffy;
    }
```

Comment: What is the syntax error that you're getting?

Comment: `$td_article_date_unix = get_the_time('U', current_time('timestamp' $this->post->ID));` your issue is on this line, a syntax-error where you have "*Unexpected variable*" error - you need some sort of separator before `$this->post->ID`.. But I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do there, because `get_the_time()` only has two arguments, and it makes no sense to pass the post-ID as the second argument for `current_time()` either. Consult the documentation for those WP functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: If I try to add my echo date code into the code from the theme I get a syntax error saying there is an error in my code.  I don't know how to correctly add the human time diff into my theme, so I just wanted to see if I could get some help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date and strtotime to determine the date/time at any distance from the current date:

```
// 2 Hours from now    
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+2 hours'))

// 30 Minutes ago   
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-30 minutes'))
```

You can then change the date format to however you please.

Hope this helps